# How to read parquet file as R data.frame without any other dependencies (like spark, python etc)?

Tags: r, parquet

I need to read some 'paraquet' files in R. There are few solution using

1. [sparklyr:: spark_read_parquet (which required 'spark')](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.9.4/topics/spark_read_parquet)
2. [reticulate (which need python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402253/how-do-i-read-a-parquet-in-r-and-convert-it-to-an-r-dataframe)

Now the problem is I am not allowed to install any tool other than R.
Is there any package available in R which can read 'paraquet' without using any other tool?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `arrow` for this (the same thing as in Python `pyarrow`) but this nowadays also comes packaged for R (without the need for Python). As it is not yet available on CRAN, you have to manually install Arrow C++ first:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow.git
cd arrow/cpp && mkdir release && cd release

# It is important to statically link to boost libraries
cmake .. -DARROW_PARQUET=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED:BOOL=Off
make install
```

Then you can install the R `arrow` package:

```
devtools::install_github("apache/arrow/r")
```

And use it to load a Parquet file

```
library(arrow)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     array, table
read_parquet("somefile.parquet", as_tibble = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>        x       y
#>    <int>   <dbl>
#> …
```

---

### Edit (22/9/2019)

It is now available on CRAN, install using `install.packages("arrow")`

Comment: cant I just use `install library(arrow)` ? do I have to type the cmd lines?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ You can now.